# How to separate layouts with weightSum in android?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I seem to be having issues understanding weightSum and LayoutWidth. My code is below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <LinearLayout

        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView

            android:padding="20sp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Cheapest Fare Option"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:background="#666666"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

My understanding of this is the 1st layout will take up 1/3 of the space and 2nd layout will take 2/3 of the space, but the reverse is happening, i.e. 1st layout is taking 2/3 and 2nd layout is taking 1/3

Why is this happening? Trying hard to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your `android:orientation="vertical"`, you want to get this ratio vertically therefore your `android:layout_height` attribute should be 0dp for both the child `LinearLayout`.

Set -

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

for both the inner `LinearLayout`.

Alternatively if you want to obtain the ratio horizontally then use `android:orientation="horizontal"` set -

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

for both the inner `LinearLayout`.

The thing is when you want to achieve ratio then you don't set that particular dimension (width or height) to match parent. Rather set it to 0dp so that Android can handle it for you automatically.

Comment: awesome, thanks! not enough reputation to display upvote!

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:padding="20sp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Cheapest Fare Option"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:background="#666666"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
</LinearLayout>
```